# Rails eager load custom has_many on index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

Ruby 2.1, Rails 3.2 
I've got this relationship in my project model

```
scope :active, -> { where( deleted_at: nil ) }
has_many :foremen, class_name: "ProjectsUser",  conditions: ['current_foreman = 1']
```

in the controller:

```
@projects = Project.includes(:foremen).active
```

which generates this SQL

```
ProjectsUser Load (3.3ms)  SELECT `projects_users`.* FROM `projects_users` WHERE `projects_users`.`project_id` IN (122, 130, ...etc.) AND ( current_foreman = 1)
```

but when i call the relationship in the view...

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= project.foremen.current_foreman %>
<% end %>
```

it runs another SQL query each time.

```
ProjectsUser Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `projects_users`.* FROM `projects_users` WHERE `projects_users`.`project_id` = 122 AND (current_foreman = 1 )
ProjectsUser Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `projects_users`.* FROM `projects_users` WHERE `projects_users`.`project_id` = 130 AND (current_foreman = 1 )
ProjectsUser Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `projects_users`.* FROM `projects_users` WHERE `projects_users`.`project_id` = 151 AND (current_foreman = 1 )
etc...
```

is am i misunderstanding something? shouldn't these records already be loaded? 
how do I write this so it only runs one query for the `ProjectsUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i did some more digging and found that my logic was correct; this does not generate any additional queries on its own. the problem was a method i was calling on the object.

the following doesn't call any queries:

```
 project.current_foremen_and_managers.select{|f| f.current_foreman}.sort_by{ |f| f.added_at}.first
```

however, when you move the extra logic into a method in the associated class, it does generate more sql

```
class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_first_foreman
    select{|f| f.current_foreman}.sort_by{ |f| f.added_at}.first
  end
end
```

then if i call this method it runs a query

```
project.current_foremen_and_managers.find_first_foreman
```

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, if anyone has an explanation I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal you are calling it inside loop of projects.